# Login based Oracle Client for tracking

Tags: oracle, client

We don’t want to share oracle DB password with all members of team but at same time we would like to give access to certain users for Select/Insert/update/create objects. Is there any login based tool where user log in with his user name and password in client tool and can then perform above operation on database. This way we can track users activity on database at same time not share actual DB password.

User will have a login and password for tool to get inside tool and then through tool they have access to database. once they are logged in the tool they will not require DB password.

Answer (score 0):

An Oracle database does not have **THE** password. Create users ([CREATE USER](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_8003.htm#SQLRF01503)) for each team member and grant him/her required privileges.

Sometimes it could be useful to create open accounts (for example `CREATE USER READONLY IDENTIFIED BY "readonly";`. Credentials for such accounts can be distributed within your organization. However, typically such users are suitable only for read/only (e.g. for reporting) accounts. You should not grant any Insert/update/create privileges.

For tracking you can use [Auditing](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/auditing.htm#DBSEG1023) or implement PL/SQL packages where changes are tracked.